# PYGAME - Blit with external class doesn't works

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have an issue with "BLIT" from an external class. When i try to display the player, it generate an issue. Same issue with items.. 
I don't understand the reason because the walls and the guardian are well display

Here is the main file

```
# -- Import Python modules
import pygame
from os import system

# -- Import personnal modules
from design import screen
from objects import player, items

system('clear')
pygame.init()


def main():
    run_game = True
    # -- Display the background and the labyrinth
    window = screen.ScreenInit()
    labyrinth = window.labyrinth_ini()
    # -- Objects and player init
    hero = player.Player(labyrinth)

    while run_game:
        pygame.time.Clock().tick(30)  # -- 30 FPS limit
        # -- Close the window game by the cross button or ESCAPE key
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT or event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN \
                    and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run_game = False

        hero.mac_position(labyrinth)

        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Here is the player screen file

```
import pygame
from design import maze, constants as cst


class ScreenInit:
    """ Screen initialisation class """
    def __init__(self):
        """ Window game settings """
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((cst.WINSIZE, cst.WINSIZE + 55))
        self.title = pygame.display.set_caption(cst.GAME_TITLE)
        self.icon = pygame.image.load(cst.MACGYVER_PIC)
        pygame.display.set_icon(self.icon)

        self.bkg = pygame.image.load(cst.BKG_PIC).convert_alpha()
        self.window.blit(self.bkg, [0, 0])

        pygame.key.set_repeat(200, 200)

    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def labyrinth_ini(self):
        """ Generate labyrinth by the file """
        self.show = maze.GameBoard('design/labyrinth')
        self.show.generate_board()
        self.show.display_board(self.window)

        pygame.display.flip()
```

Here is the player file

```
import pygame
from design import constants as cst

class Player:
    """ Class for MacGyver management """
    def __init__(self, zone):
        """ MacGyver pic and start position init """
        self.pos_x = 0
        self.pos_y = 0
        self.cell_x = 0
        self.cell_y = 0
        self.zone = zone

        self.mac_pic = pygame.image.load(cst.MACGYVER_PIC).convert_alpha()

    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def mac_position(self, zone):
        zone.blit(self.mac_pic, self.pos_x, self.pos_y)

    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def mac_moves(self):
        pass
```

Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/PYTHON/game.py", line 43, in main
    hero.mac_position(labyrinth)
  File "/home/user/PYTHON/objects/player.py", line 22, in mac_position
    zone.blit(self.mac_pic, self.pos_x, self.pos_y)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'blit'
```

If you have an idea... I tried a lot of things.. It makes me crazy since 3 days ! Many thanks

Comment: Arf.. Thank you but already tried.. ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/PYTHON/game.py", line 43, in main
    hero.mac_position()
  File "/home/user/PYTHON/objects/player.py", line 22, in mac_position
    self.zone.blit(self.mac_pic, self.pos_x, self.pos_y)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'blit'
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved... If it cans help anyone. 
In this case, there was a word missing : 'window'

```
zone.window.blit(self.mac_pic, [self.pos_x, self.pos_y])
```